# Why does PSQL ignore spatial index in "where NOT ST_Contains", but uses in "where ST_Contains"?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, spatial-join, spatial-index

I'm creating a new table of trips in my PostgreSQL/PostGIS database, where trips are comprised of a series of individually identified points, based on where the points within each trip are. The idea is to select *any* trip which has at least one point that is NOT within a certain area. So that means filtering through every point to see if it's in or out of a certain spatial realm, and if any point is outside of the realm, then I put the trip_id of that point (multiple points make up a single trip, and all points within a trip share a trip_id) into this new table. The query is written as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE main.trips_gps_validity_21 as
    SELECT DISTINCT t.trip_id 
    FROM main.points t, main.sfoutline y
    WHERE not(ST_Contains(y.geom, t.geom_met))
```

Here, y.geom is the spatial polygon that designates my area of interest, and the t.geom_met is the geometry for each point within a trip.

When I run the inverse, i.e. the bottom line is "WHERE ST_Contains(y.geom, t.geom_met)" **instead** of "WHERE NOT", the spatial index is used. When the "NOT" is applied, the spatial index is ignored. Why would this be happening? Running the "NOT" query with a "limit 10" addendum takes 2.953 seconds, while the query without "NOT" takes only 90 msecs, so it seems like an index would help speed things along.

Comment: Proving a negative is always a tricky task.  You might have better luck with `ST_Disjoint`

Comment: Try a workaround be selecting `where t.trip_id not in.. [fast ST_Contains query]`. But if ST_Contains finds just a handful of features and NOT ST_Contains much more the difference in speed may be normal.